# Broken link within an email sent with PHP

Tags: php, email, hyperlink, html-email

I have run into a strange problem trying to send a link with an email using php. This link will simply bring a user to an "Update Password" form. However, when I click the link it brings me to a blank page in my browser called "about:blank". I don't really understand why this is happening... Here is my code: The html for the link is inside the $msg variable.

```
$to     = $email;

$msg    = "Hello $username, your pin # is $pin. Please remember this pin
                because you will need it on the update password form. <br> 
                Please <a href = \"google.com\">click here</a> to be brought to the update password form.";

$header  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$header .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$header .= 'From: ForgottenPassword@PHPGang.com' . "\r\n" .
                'Reply-To: ForgottenPassword@PHPGang.com' . "\r\n" .
                'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();    

mail($to,"Forgotten Password",$msg,$header);
```

I even tried putting google.com as the destination, but it still brings me to that pesky about:blank page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a fully qualified URL, protocol and all, in your link.

```
$msg    = "Hello $username, your pin # is $pin. Please remember this pin
                because you will need it on the update password form. <br> 
                Please <a href = \"http://google.com\">click here</a> to be brought to the update password form.";
```

Answer (score 1):

try to change as below,here you are missing to add http to the url,

```
<a href = \"google.com\">click here</a>
```

to

```
<a href = \"http://google.com\">click here</a>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO. *This is not the first time that you have been asked to qualify your answers better.*